# How to install SIP+PyQt with apt-get + pip + virtualenv?

Tags: apt, python, qt, pyqt

[I originally posted this question, under a different title, in StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17265845/559827)), but later I realized that my problem is very specific to `apt-get`, hence I am re-posting it here.  Sorry for the duplication.]

I'm trying to install PyQt on Ubuntu (and within a virtualenv).  The list of obstacles I'm dealing with is far too long to include here, but the one I'm currently trying to get past is this:

```
% workon myvenv
(myvenv)% cd ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/pyqt
(myvenv)% python ./configure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 32, in <module>
    import sipconfig
```

OK, so let's install `sipconfig`...

```
(myvenv)% pip install SIP
Downloading/unpacking SIP
  Downloading sip-4.14.8-snapshot-02bdf6cc32c1.zip (848Kb): 848Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package SIP
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP
Storing complete log in /home/yt/.pip/pip.log
```

The only recipe I've found so far installing SIP is this

```
% python configure.py
% make
% sudo make install
```

...but this recipe goes against my policy of doing all my Ubuntu installations either through `apt-get` (or through `pip` in the case of Python modules).

Is there some way that I can install SIP with apt-get (and possibly pip)?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that `virtualenv` seems to prefer to symlink `/usr/include` instead of copying those files to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/include` (you can check this while inspecting the source code of `virtualenv`: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py` in my system).

An easy solution would be just remove the symlink and copy those files from `/usr/include`:

```
$ cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/include/
$ rm python2.7
$ cp -r /usr/include/python2.7/ .
```

Please note that you may have symlinks on `/usr/include/python2.7` pointing to relative locations, so when you copy those files they will become broken.

Then you only need a little modification:

```
$ python configure.py --incdir="$VIRTUAL_ENV/include/python2.7"
$ make
$ make install
```

BTW: if you want to force `virtualenv` to copy those files instead of symlink'ing, just change the definition of `copyfile` in the source code file. It's a ugly solution but works.

```
def copyfile(src, dest, symlink=True):
                                 |-> change this to False
```